# Ansible: how to manage hosts if they are not always online?

Tags: ansible, update, configuration-management

My apologies if this question has been asked before, but I may not be using the correct terminology in my searches...

In my spare time I'm managing a limited amount of hosts (desktops and laptops running Debian Stretch) with Ansible. My 'installer playbook' creates a single configuration on all those hosts with different hardware to make management much easier. I'm now manually running an updater role from time to time and every once in a while I find a useful tweak that I then deploy to those hosts that are online. But: some of them rarely come to the office, and if they are available for an update, it's always a hassle to determine which tweaks I still have to deploy on that machine...

Sure, I can:

- write an epoch timestamp (`{{ ansible_date_time.epoch }}`) to a file on each host that can be retrieved and set as a fact
- create a new task for each new tweak, adding a tag with the epoch timestamp and a conditional to check whether the epoch-fact > epoch-tag
- update the epoch timestamp on the host after a successful playbook run

Is this how it should be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if they are available for an update, it's always a hassle to determine which tweaks I still have to deploy on that machine...

That is not the way to use Ansible. Your playbooks should be written in a way that it doesn't matter if you have applied a configuration set before (["idempotence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence)). If they are, you just can apply the latest version of the playbook and your systems should end up in the correct state.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I know the concept, and I believe my tasks are idempotent, but if I have to run the entire playbook each time, it doesn't strike me as efficient... If this is the correct way to do it in Ansible, then ok.

Comment: In daily operations, I often use the different selectors (tags, hosts etc.) Ansible offers, but for machines I don't see regularly, I would just apply the full playbook.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a good use-case for [ansible-pull](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/ansible-pull.html). Hosts which are not permanent online could be configured to run ansible-pull when connected to the office network.

However that doesn't change the need to create idempotent playbook and roles. If the running time of a playbook is a issue there is the option to use `stat` module to set conditions to skip longer running tasks.

Selectors are a option here, but those require manual management. So it might be better to speed up the execution time of playbook itself.